# Coefficient Correlation Proof

Tags: statistical-inference, covariance, correlation

Let the correlation coefficient between X and Y be $\rho$.

Show that the correlation coefficient between $aX + b$ and $cY + d$
can also be equal to $\rho$. Currently,
I am trying to understand this concept to build a strong foundation in inferential statistics.

I understand that (and hopefully this is correct) $$\rho = Cov(X,Y)/\sigma_x\sigma_y$$ and that can eventually be algebraically deduced to be $$E[(X-E(X)/\sigma_x)]E[(Y-E(X)/\sigma_Y)] $$

Can someone explain to me how this can be related to the fact that $aX + b$ and $cY + d$
can also be equal to $\rho$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that expectation is linear, i.e. $E(\alpha X+\beta Y)=\alpha E(X)+\beta E(Y)$?

Comment: What does that imply?

Comment: The way I remember the formula for $\rho$: In $\Bbb R^n$ let the origin be $O$. Let $X,Y\in \Bbb R^n$ with $X\ne O\ne Y$.  "Normalize" $X,Y$ with $X'=X-E(X)$  and $Y'=Y-E(Y).$ Then $\rho = \cos \angle X'OY'=\frac {<X',Y'>}{\|X'\|\cdot \|Y'\|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is linear making it quite easy.

$$\begin{split}\rho'&=\frac{Cov(aX+b, cY+d)}{\sigma_{aX+b}\sigma_{cY+d}}\\
&=\frac{acCov(X, Y)}{a\sigma_Xc\sigma_Y}\\
&=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}\\
&=\rho\end{split}$$

Comment: note that this is only true when $a, c>0$ or $a, c<0$